# Add horizontal scroll bar to mat-chip

Tags: html, css, angular

I cant figure out how to add horizontal scrolling to the mat-chip-list. Any Ideas? I think it has to do something with overriding the changes of mat-chip-list-wrapper.

```css
.search-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    margin-left: 6%;
}
div.mat-chip-list-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  .mat-chip {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
}
.mat-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
    <mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let $searchTerm of ($searchTerms | async)" [removable]="$searchTerm.removable" (removed)="removeSearchTerm(searchTerm)"  [matTooltip]="searchTerm">
            <mat-icon matSuffix>{{$searchTerm.icon}}</mat-icon>
            {{$searchTerm.value}} 
            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="$searchTerm.removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
    <div class="search">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" class="remove-underline trim-whitespace">
            <span matPrefix><mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon></span>
            <input matInput (keyup)="onSearchTerm($event)" placeholder="Search"  [(ngModel)]="searchInput">
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-button (click)="submitSearchTerm()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChuZT.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think example here can provide answer for that

[Horizontal menu - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_hor_scroll)

Overflow and white-space combination is crucial for that.

---

### EDIT:

```
.scrollable {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

mat-chip{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xotu9qgj/20/)

I added a div for the list and made it scrollable.

Comment: I tried doing it that way but it wasnt working for mw

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/xotu9qgj/18/. I added div for list which is made scrollable.

Comment: The would make the input box also scrollable which i dont really want

Comment: My bad editing. Here is update with div in good position. http://jsfiddle.net/xotu9qgj/20/

Comment: It add the scroll but i dont want the chips to keep moving down. i want to be able to scroll right to see all the chips

Comment: I think display: inline-block is causing that issue

Comment: I think I don't understand your aim as I see nothing moving down in fiddle I sent.

Comment: Basically i just want one horizontal line that has all my chips

Comment: For me it http://jsfiddle.net/xotu9qgj/21/ looks like it. If something wrong pls provide example which is not horizontal.

Comment: The link I added is the result im getting

Comment: So probably it is the feature of Material Design style of chips which as I see works different from pure HTML. Maybe there is a workaround, but I don't know well this component so unfortunately I can't help with that.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Imho put it in the answer so it will be more visible for others looking for similar problem.

Comment: @Karam Were you able to solve this problem? I was facing the same problem where the  chips keep moving down.

Answer (score 1):

Someone made a good [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/share-angular-chips-q8qas4?file=app%2Fchips-stacked-example.scss).

The code basically boils down to:

```
div.mat-chip-list-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;

  .mat-chip {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
}
```